# How to remove item in Droplist with same name, but different value on hover in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I have 2 droplists. One list contains items with a name and value, the other one contains only the name. What i want is to drag the item with value to the list where the value is not set and when i hover over the item with the name, it needs to be removed in the list so that the item with value can take its place.

The problem is that when i hover over the item without value, it just shifts under the draggable item.

Component.ts

```
TYPESCRIPT / ANGULAR
appAttributes: CsvFile[] = [
    {name: 'Telefoonnummer', value: ''},
    {name: 'Gender', value: ''},
    {name: 'Woonplaats', value: ''},
    {name: 'Straat', value: ''},
    {name: 'Huisnummer', value: ''},
    {name: 'Toevoeging', value: ''},
  ]
  csvFile: CsvFile[] = [
    {name: 'Telefoonnummer', value: '0625097357'},
    {name: 'Gender', value: 'Man'},
    {name: 'Woonplaats', value: 'Gieten'},
    {name: 'Straat', value: 'Gietsenakkers'},
    {name: 'Huisnummer', value: '2'},
    {name: 'Toevoeging', value: ''},
  ]

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<CsvFile[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else if (event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex].name == event.container.data[event.currentIndex].name) {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex,
      );
      this.appAttributes.splice( event.currentIndex+1, 1)
    }
  }
```

component.html

```
HTML
<div class="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-evenly">
      <div style="width: 320px"
        cdkDropList
        #csvFileList="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="csvFile"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[placeholderList]"
        [cdkDropListAutoScrollDisabled]="true"
        [cdkDropListSortingDisabled]="true"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div [cdkDragDisabled]="item.value.length == 0" cdkDrag cdkDragHandle *ngFor="let item of csvFile; let index = index">
          <div style="height: 52px" class="bg-light shadow-sm border rounded text-secondary mb-2 p-2">
            <div class="ms-2">
              {{item.name}}
              <div class="text-dark">
                {{item.value | truncate: [20, '...']}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="border-end border-light-5"></div>

      <div style="width: 320px"
        cdkDropList
        #placeholderList="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="appAttributes"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[csvFileList]"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="true" *ngFor="let item of appAttributes; let index = index">
          <div [ngStyle]="{'border': (item.value.length == 0 ? '1px dashed' : '1px solid')}" style="height: 52px" [class]="'shadow-sm border-border-color rounded text-secondary mb-2 p-2 ' + (item.value.length == 0 ? 'bg-body' : 'bg-light')">
            <div class="ms-2">
              {{item.name}} <span class="text-dark" *ngIf="item.name == uniqueFeature">(Uniek kenmerk)</span>
              <div class="text-dark">
                {{item.value | truncate: [20, '...']}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```